# Sample Ant project with all the 'features' of Maven?

Tags: maven-2, ant

The past week or two I've been studying Maven, and I like it, but there are just a few things that I require Ant tasks for, rather than Maven's complicated and scarcely-documented POM file. However, I believe Maven has a great folder structure going for it, and I like that it natively supports tests, packages the project into a jar by default, and supports a 'resources' folder, from which everything is directly copied into the jar file.

Is there a sample Ant project out there that does the same sort of thing but with an Ant build.xml script? I want the placeholder folders and hello world app and test, just like Maven does when you first create a project from its default archetype:create goal (as demonstrated in the [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) page). Or, is there an even better Ant sample project out there that does more or suggests a better folder layout?

If no such thing exists, perhaps someone can help create it in a nice detailed answer? I would be willing to host a permanently-available zip file for anyone who finds this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn archetype:create
mvn ant:ant
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/usage.html

... but if there are really "just a few things", you may want to check out the [AntRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin instead.  I'm not trying to sell you on Maven, believe me, but since it's not clear exactly what is stopping you from trying it with your project, I guess I'm suggesting you try to push the issue a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this: [Why you should use the Maven Ant Tasks instead of Maven or Ivy](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/why-you-should-use-the-maven-ant-tasks-instead-of-maven-or-ivy/)

I also wouldn't recommend Ivy, reasons at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [Maven - Frequently Asked Technical Questions](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#maven-ant-tasks) and more precisely:

> #### How can I use Maven features in an Ant build?
>
> The [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) allow many of the
> features of Maven, such as dependency
> management and repository deployment,
> to be used in an Ant build.

Refer to the [installation page](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/installation.html) and the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html) for instructions for installing and using the Maven Ant Tasks respectively. You'll find many links to samples in the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html) and a [build.xml](https://github.com/apache/maven-ant-tasks/blob/maven-ant-tasks-2.0.10/sample.build.xml) showing most of the features in action.

An alternative (direct competitor?) to Maven Ant Tasks would be [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

PS: While it's definitely a good idea to adopt maven standards, even partially, I'd really think about it twice before to drop Maven (but I live in the Maven jungle for a while now - and I like it - so I'm biased).